# VBA - How to triplet each cell in the array

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop, unique

I'm trying to get all the unique values in column A and insert them to the array: "uniqueNameList".

after that, I want to triplet each cell in my array.

**For example:**

column A:

| A |
| --- |
| One |
| Two |
| Three |
| Three |
| One |
| Two |

**the "uniqueNameList" array will be:**

("One" , "Two", "Three")

**And after triplet it will be:**

("One" ,"One" ,"One" , "Two", "Two", "Two", "Three", "Three", "Three")

I've tried this and I do get the "uniqueNameList" array as expected.
but I didn't manage to triplet the Items. This is my code:

```
Sub test()

Dim myList As Variant, uniqueNameList As Variant, arr3 As Variant
Dim itemCount As Long
myList = shTest.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
uniqueNameList = WorksheetFunction.Unique(myList)
itemCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(uniqueNameList)
ReDim arr3(1 To (itemCount * 3))
Dim i As Long, j As Long

For i = 1 To UBound(uniqueNameList)
    
    arr3(i) = uniqueNameList(i, 1)
    arr3(i + 1) = uniqueNameList(i, 1)
    arr3(i + 2) = uniqueNameList(i, 1)
    
Next i


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to multiply the index for `arr3` by 3. For the first iteration (i=1), you want to write into index 1, 2, 3, for the second interation (i=2) into 4, 5, 6 and so on.

```
For i = 1 To UBound(uniqueNameList)
    arr3(i * 3 - 2) = uniqueNameList(i, 1)
    arr3(i * 3 - 1) = uniqueNameList(i, 1)
    arr3(i * 3 - 0) = uniqueNameList(i, 1)
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

if your uniquenamelist array starts from 0 and arr3 starts from 1 then try this.

```
`For i = LBound(uniqueNameList) To UBound(uniqueNameList)
    
    arr3((3 * i) + 1) = uniqueNameList(i)
    arr3((3 * i) + 2) = uniqueNameList(i)
    arr3((3 * i) + 3) = uniqueNameList(i)
    
Next i
```

`